# create a dynamic selectlist with distinct values from LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to create a dynamic `SelectList` in C# using `Linq` below is my query

```
ViewBag.net = new SelectList(db.nw.Where(m => m.client_id == 
ClientId).OrderBy(m => m.nw_ename), "nw_ename", "nw_ename");
```

This is working fine and returning the data, but it has some duplicate values, so I need to use `Distinct`. While using distinct I am not able to write the LINQ statement. The below one is what I tried.

```
ViewBag.net = new SelectList((from m in db.np_nw_providers
                              where m.client_id == ClientId                                                                       
                              select m.nw_ename
                            ).Distinct()
                             .OrderBy(nw_enam => nw_enam), "m.nw_ename", "m.nw_ename");
```

when running this I am getting an error

> DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name
>   'm'.

How can I achieve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only wanting the `nw_enam` property, you can use

```
var items = db.nw.Where(m => m.client_id == ClientId)
                 .OrderBy(m => m.nw_enam)
                 .Select(i => i.nw_enam)
                 .Distinct();
ViewBag.net = new SelectList(items);
```

Comment: You'd better use ViewModels than the Viewbag. StronglyTypedViews are far more easy to manage this way.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `"m.nw_ename"` arguments from `SelectList` constructor

```
var query = (from m in db.np_nw_providers
             where m.client_id == ClientId                                                                       
             select m.nw_ename
            ).Distinct()
             .OrderBy(nw_enam => nw_enam);

ViewBag.net = new SelectList(query);
```

Comment: Your fist suggestion didn't worked..but this one is fine..thanks.